# How to create bar plot ro show Median by class

Tags: r

> Q5:    Here is your first challenge of Tidyverse. Load the
> `MarathonData.csv` dataset. Remember the three function we just
> introduced? Time to apply them on this new set!
>
> - select all the observations whose Category is M40
> - find the median value of Marathon time and maximum value of km4week within each class, saving them into medianTime and maxWeeks,
>   respectively
> - sort in descending order by that maxWeeks
> - create a bar plot to show the median Marathon time by class.

I have understood the first part where all observations whose Category M40 has to be selected.

However need assistance in how the code would be written for the other parts.

Comment: Welcome. What did  you try so far? You're more likely to get a good answer if you show some attempts, as well as sharing the data using ``dput()``. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the `iris` dataset example in which a column category was added to demonstrate filtering:

```r
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
  mutate(category = rep(c(0,1), 75)) %>%
  filter(category == 1) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(median = median(Sepal.Length), maximum = max(Petal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(reorder(Species, -maximum), median)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>